# Unable to access 3ware 3dm2 web interface, failed to start listening socket

Tags: debian, service, socket, 3ware

I am unable to get to the 3ware 3dm2 web interface. When I attempt to execute 3dm2 from the command line, i get the following error "(0x0C:0x0005): Failed to start listening socket". This was working years ago, but now that I'm trying to access it for my new RAID install, I am unable to access the web interface.

The service appears to be running, and I am not using any iptables firewall

```
# netstat -tupl
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program     
tcp        0      0 *:888                   *:*                     LISTEN      5191/3dm2       

# nmap -sT 127.0.0.1
PORT    STATE SERVICE
888/tcp open  accessbuilder
```

I am on 32-bit debian 6.0.9 (squeeze), with 9650se-4lpml and a 7506-4LP. The 3ware-3dm2- package was installed using aptitude and is at version 9.3.0.4-1duo1.

Any help is appreciated. Hopefully it is something simple.

Comment: The service is already running. Why are you trying to run it more?

Comment: The service is running but I am unable to connect to the web interface at https://<ip address>:888

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: the webpage is not available

Comment: Try with http:// not https://?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect from another computer? If so, in **/etc/3dmd2/3dmd2.conf** you need to change:

```
RemoteAccess 0
```

to:

```
RemoteAccess 1
```

And restart the service.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was hoping this was it. I am connecting from another computer (the server does not have X), but after checking, RemoteAccess is already set to 1.

Comment: The 3dm2 software should do some logging, can you find any log files in the directory where it was installed?

Comment: I cant seem to find anything being generated in /etc/3dm2 /usr/share/3dm2 or /var/log. The only thing I can think of is that this binary is not working on wheezy

Comment: Try to run it with strace and see what it tells you. I have used 3dm2 a lot and I can't remember other pitfals than the one I mentioned, using https and the default password. It's quite well behaved.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this exact problem. For me, the solution was:

1. Stop the tdm2 service (example applies to CloudLinux 7.9; your init path may vary):

   `/etc/init.d/tdm2 stop`
2. Delete the following lockfile:

   `rm -f /var/lock/subsys/3dm2`
3. Start the tdm2 service:

   `/etc/init.d/tdm2 start`

After this, the UI should once again be available.

For some reason, the lock file wasn't being removed when the server was rebooted or the service restarted. Manually removing the lock file was required to restore correct operation.

Note: Modern browsers in 2023 now have **TLS 1.0/1.1 disabled** and entirely unavailable. You'll need to have an older browser available, e.g., Firefox 96 or earlier, to have access to older TLS protocols.